# Convertir pixeles a centimetros en open cv

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy realizando un codigo de open cv que mediante flujo optico mide el desplazamiento, actualmente tengo una conversion mediante una regresion lineal , sin embargo es poco precisa , me gustaria saber que otros metodos existen para este fin usando python y open cv para poder medir centimetros mediante una webcam usb, el propósito es que el programa detecte puntos de interes, y registre el cambio a traves del tiempo, y que ese cambio se mida en centimetros , por ello necesito convertir de pixeles a centimetros

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Parámetros para el algoritmo de Lucas-Kanade
lk_params = dict(winSize=(15, 15),
                 maxLevel=2,
                 criteria=(cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))

# Parámetros para la detección de esquinas ShiTomasi
feature_params = dict(maxCorners=2,
                      qualityLevel=0.7,
                      minDistance=7,
                      blockSize=7)

# Resolución de la cámara
resolucion_x = 1280
resolucion_y = 720

# Distancia real a la que se encuentra la cámara (cm)
distancia_real = 182

# Función para convertir píxeles a centímetros
def pixeles_a_centimetros(x, resolucion):
    return (x / resolucion) * distancia_real

# Crear  colores aleatorios
color = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 3))

# Captura de video 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Establece la resolución 
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, resolucion_x)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, resolucion_y)

# Establece la tasa de fotogramas por segundo
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)

# Comprueba si la cámara se ha abierto correctamente
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error al abrir la cámara")
    exit()

# Toma el primer frame y encuentra las esquinas en él
ret, old_frame = cap.read()
if ret:
    old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask=None, **feature_params)
else:
    print("Error al leer la cámara")
    exit()

# Crea una máscara para dibujar sobre ella
mask = np.zeros_like(old_frame)

# Guarda el primer punto detectado como el origen
origin = p0[0]

# Establece el tiempo entre mediciones en milisegundos 
tiempo_entre_mediciones = 25

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Calcula el Flujo Óptico
    p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)

    # Selecciona solo las mejores coincidencias
    good_new = p1[st == 1]
    good_old = p0[st == 1]

    # Dibuja las pistas y calcula el desplazamiento
    for i, (new, old) in enumerate(zip(good_new, good_old)):
        a, b = new.ravel().astype(int)
        c, d = old.ravel().astype(int)
        mask = cv2.line(mask, (a, b), (c, d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
        frame = cv2.circle(frame, (a, b), 5, color[i].tolist(), -1)

        # Calcula el desplazamiento respecto al origen
        displacement_x_pixels = a - origin[0][0]
        displacement_y_pixels = origin[0][1] - b  # Invierte el eje Y

        # Convierte desplazamiento de píxeles a centímetros usando la función lineal
        displacement_x_cm = pixeles_a_centimetros(displacement_x_pixels, resolucion_x)
        displacement_y_cm = pixeles_a_centimetros(displacement_y_pixels, resolucion_y)

        print(f"Desplazamiento en x: {displacement_x_cm} cm, Desplazamiento en y: {displacement_y_cm} cm")

    img = cv2.add(frame, mask)

    # Muestra la imagen
    cv2.imshow('Frame', img)

    # Actualiza el frame y los puntos anteriores
    old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
    p0 = good_new.reshape(-1, 1, 2)

    # Espera el tiempo especificado antes de la siguiente medición
    key = cv2.waitKey(tiempo_entre_mediciones)

    # Interrumpe si se presiona ESC
    if key & 0xFF == 27:
        break

# Cierra todas las ventanas
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```